# Object reference not set to an instance of an object on adding an object to a list

Tags: c#

In the following code for, yet an unknown to me  reason it keeps on throwing a the exception in the title.

```
            try
        {
            conn.Open();
            createDraw.ExecuteNonQuery();
            rdr = getDrawId.ExecuteReader();
            string rd = rdr[0].ToString();
            int tid = Int32.Parse(rd);

            Drawing dr = new Drawing(tid, pos, orientation, defaultColour, 200.0, 300.0, fname, "local");
            this.NoteScatterView.Items.Add(dr.getSvi());
            if (dr != null) { drawings.Add(dr); }

        }
        catch (Exception ex) { Microsoft.Surface.UserNotifications.RequestNotification("Unable to create Drawing", ex.Message + "in Session.createDrawing"); }
```

I'm just trying to add the drawing object in a list of Drawings

```
        private List<Drawing> drawings;
```

for later use, but I don't know why this exception is thrown.

Comment: What is the line on which the exception is thrown?

Comment: Hard to say why you get the exception without knowing in which line the exception occurs...

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You need to create an instance of List

```
private List<Drawing> drawings = new List<Drawing>();
```

Answer (score 1):

Make sure drawings is initialized:

```
private List<Drawing> drawings = new List<Drawing>();
```